# How to simplify this css code?

Tags: css

```
div.a b, div.a strong, div.a i, div.a form, div.a span  {
  color: red
}
```

How to simplify this? To use `div.a` just once if possible, that would be perfection.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)/[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: Do you want anything under `div.a` to be `color: red`?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret No. Just defined elements.

Comment: Oh, then with regular ol' CSS I don't think it can get shorter. You could omit the `'div'` in `'div.a'` if it's OK for all `class="a"` elements to behave similarly.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to simplify it, you would put a common class on all of the elements, such that you have:

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This really seems like the way to go.  I think it makes the html/css easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

If you are targeting all child elements of `div.a`:

```
div.a *  {
    color: red
}
```

If you would like to not include a certain one, you could just use `:not()` of course.

Also, you could use [less](http://lesscss.org/), which allows you to use:

```
div.a  {
    b, strong, i, form, span {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
div.a * { color: red; }
```

Every element under the `<div class="a">` would have red text color, unless otherwise overridden.

If you only need `b`, `form`, `strong`, `span`, `i` to be red, then you probably have the shortest it can get without adding a class, such as what is proposed in the other answer.